# ASP.NET GridView doesn't save update in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

SELECT works, Edit button works, but after editing, when I press "Save" the Grid is back to before changes and there is no change in the database. SELECT is using 3 tables, UPDATE is supposed to update only the main one, but still nothing happens.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="idw" AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceGrid">        
   <Columns>
     <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="idw" HeaderText="idw" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="idw" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="name" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="surname" HeaderText="surname" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="surname" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="item_name" HeaderText="item_name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="item_name" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="item_serial" HeaderText="item_serial" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="item_serial" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="date_taken" HeaderText="date_taken" SortExpression="date_taken" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="notes" HeaderText="notes" SortExpression="notes" />
   </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceGrid" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WarehouseConnectionString %>" 
 SelectCommand="SELECT idw, name, surname, item_name, item_serial, date_taken, notes FROM Warehouse w JOIN Users u ON w.idu=u.idu JOIN Items i ON i.ids=i.ids" 
 UpdateCommand="UPDATE Warehouse SET date_taken=@date_taken, notes=@notes WHERE idw=@idw">
 <UpdateParameters>
   <asp:Parameter Name="date_taken" />
   <asp:Parameter Name="notes" />
   <asp:Parameter Name="idw" />
 </UpdateParameters>
```

I've read multiple examples and tutorials and everything should be fine. I've "manually" written the SELECT and UPDATE commands in SqlDataSource, maybe that's the problem?

Thanks in advance for any kind of advice.

Comment: Did you read this article **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx** ??

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Yea and I think my code is similar. I couldn't auto-generate insert, update, delete when I was using custom select query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used code-behind solution in the end, manually coding:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string id = ...
    string notes = ...    
    UpdateDB(id, notes);    
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    bind_grid();
}
```

Which might actually give me more control over data.

Answer (score 0):

```
maybe that's the problem?
```

After the last note, now I see that you have set `ReadOnly="True"` on the values that you try to update. Change that to false (or remove it), and they will be update.

Comment: Types don't help and in UpdateParameters I only have the params that are not ReadOnlym, and the ID.

Comment: Now I see, you have set ReadOnly=true, this is the problem ! change them.

Comment: I have ReadOnly on fields that I don't update... I'm updating only "date_taken" and "notes".

Comment: @yosh but this noes and date_taken is not on your updateparametre list.

Comment: How come...? I have: <UpdateParameters>
   <asp:Parameter Name="date_taken" />
   <asp:Parameter Name="notes" />
   <asp:Parameter Name="idw" />
 </UpdateParameters>

Answer (score 0):

See this below Example and try to change the code as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="EmployeeId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" 
                ShowSelectButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeId" HeaderText="EmployeeId" 
                InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="EmployeeId" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Salary" HeaderText="Salary" 
                SortExpression="Salary" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Employee] WHERE [EmployeeId] = @EmployeeId" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Employee] ([Name], [Salary]) VALUES (@Name, @Salary)" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Employee]" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Employee] SET [Name] = @Name, [Salary] = @Salary WHERE [EmployeeId] = @EmployeeId">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="EmployeeId" Type="Int64" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Salary" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Salary" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="EmployeeId" Type="Int64" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: How is this different than mine? I don't need delete and insert.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark a GridView column as non-editable by settings its ReadOnly property to True. Try to delete this property. Also, set the type of the updateparameters - that is DateTime, string and int32 in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually write that from code behind:

```
SqlDataSourceGrid.UpdateCommand = "UPDATE Warehouse SET date_taken=date_taken1, notes=note1 WHERE idw=1";
```